# Unexpected result doing 64-bit negative integer arithmetic

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

The best way to illustrate my question is through this snippet from my actual code:

```
ULONG uiDelaySec = 5;

ULONGLONG iiDaysOver = 0;
LONGLONG ii = -10000000LL * (LONGLONG)uiDelaySec / (2 + iiDaysOver);

//Why do I get 'ii' equal to 9223372036829775808?
```

PS. I'm running this code in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: and how do you _print_ it?

Comment: How do you check the value of `ii`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Via a debugger pane in VS.

Comment: Debugger pane in VS is correct in Hex view. If you sprintf your variable is correct -25000000. Debugger pane non hex view is bugged i consider the number as uint64_t

Comment: @LPs: `9223372036829775808` is `0x7FFFFFFFFE8287C0` while `-25000000` is `FFFFFFFFFE8287C0`.

Comment: @c00000fd then is bugged. sprintf prints the value correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let consider how this statement

```
LONGLONG ii = -10000000LL * (LONGLONG)uiDelaySec / (2 + iiDaysOver);
```

is executed step by step.

At first there is executed subexpression

```
-10000000LL * (LONGLONG)uiDelaySec
```

It has type `LONGLONG` and its value is

```
-50000000
```

Then this result has to be divided by operand `(2 + iiDaysOver)` of type `ULONGLONG` because `iiDaysOver` is defined like

```
ULONGLONG iiDaysOver = 0;
```

To perform the operation the compiler shall to use the common type for its operands. The left operand has type `LONGLONG` while the right operand has type `ULONGLONG`. According to the rules of the usual arithmetic conversions signed type is converted to unsigned type if the both types have the same rank.

From the C Standard

6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers

> — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the
>   corresponding signed integer type, if any.

and

6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions

> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Thus the left operand will be converted to type `ULONGLONG`. And you will get that the negative value of the left operand

```
-50000000
```

interpretated as a non-negative value will have value

```
18446744073659551616
```

To be sure that it is indeed valid you can insert statement

```
printf( "%llu\n", ( unsigned long long )-50000000LL );
```

or if to use your typedef(s) for fundamental types

```
printf( "%llu\n", ( ULONGLONG )-50000000LL );
```

Dividing this value by 2 you will get unsigned value

```
9223372036829775808?
```

that can be represented as a non-negative value in both types: `LONGLONG` and `ULONGLONG.` So this value will be assigned to `ii` without any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Debugger pane in VS is bugged. If you sprintf your variable is correct `-25000000`.

The very strange thing is that if I changed the code as below the debug pane is correct.

```
int64_t ii = -10000000LL;
ii = ii * (int64_t)uiDelaySec;
ii /= (uint32_t)(2);
```

The key point is if the last division: if it is performed with uint64_t the debug view is bugged, with uint32_t is not...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in the division of `-10000000LL * (long long)uiDelaySec` by `(2 + iiDaysOver)`, since the latter one is an unsigned long long int, the former one is an unsigned value. My C-Fu is not strong enough to explain why this happens, but the following line gives the expected result, at least using gcc:

```
long long int ii = -10000000LL * (long long)uiDelaySec / (long long int)(2 + iiDaysOver);
```